# Не устанавливается React ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED

Tags: create-react-app

После выполнения команд как указано в https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn start или npm start
```

Возникает ошибка. Кто нибудь знает в чём дело? Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось вылечить проблему после установки `node 14.18.1 LTS` вместо текущей `node 17.0.1`